# Programmatically add songs to iTunes

Tags: python, itunes, osx-mountain-lion

Is it possible to add songs to iTunes on OS X programmatically? I.e. say I have a directory of songs I'd like to add to iTunes from a Python script. What is the easiest way to achieve that?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's possible, but with using AppleScript. What have you tried? Although it's possible to steer AppleScript from Python, in my experience that has been a painful affair in the past.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: hmm, I don't have much experience with AppleScript, let me look this up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iTunes has a special folder where it looks for music files to add it automatically to its library:

```
/Users/<your_username>/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes
```

(move to this folder by

`cd /Users/<your_username>/Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Media/Automatically\ Add\ to\ iTunes`)

All you have to do is to write a python or shell script that copies your music into this folder.
e.g., for python

```
import commands
commands.getoutput("cp file.mp3 /Users/<your_username>/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to iTunes")
```

Comment: current path looks more like this ATM `/Users/<your_username>/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Automatically Add to Music.localized`